# Problem with ask (alexa skill kit) CLI- ask deploy and ask dialog/simulate creating odd error. Maybe problem with connecting to the endpoint

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-sdk-nodejs, ask-cli

Everything worked fine, until I started to get this error when I use "ask dialog":
[image: picture of the error]

> Error: This utterance did not resolve to any intent in your skill. Please invoke your skill and try again with a different utterance or update your interaction model to include this utterance before testing again.

After a few tries, I tried to deploy my changes, and see if I can test properly in the console.

It didn't work, although it seems the deployment was successful. I tried to change my profile in "ask init", I tried to remove and reinstall ask-CLI, but this also didn't work.

I tried to clone a skill I had created in the console, and it worked, but when I tried to make changes and deploy, the error came back.

I tried to use "ask simulate" with  `--force-new-session`, but it still didn't work.

I ran "ask dialog" and "ask simulate" with `--debug`,

This is the output-

```
{
"id": "fb2869d0-a324-42f6-bca9-4adc0af3476f",
"status": "FAILED",
"result": {
"alexaExecutionInfo": {
"consideredIntents": [
{ 
"name": "<IntentForDifferentSkill>"
}   
]
},

"error": {
"message": "This utterance did not resolve to any intent in your skill. Please invoke your skill and try again with a different utterance or update your interaction model to include this utterance before testing again."
}
```

And when I inserted it to lambda test, the output was-

```
{    
"errorType": "TypeError",   
"errorMessage": "handlerInput.t is not a function",    
"trace": [    
"TypeError: handlerInput.t is not a function",    
" at Object.handle (/var/task/index.js:133:42)",    
" at GenericRequestDispatcher.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/ask-sdk-runtime/dist/dispatcher/GenericRequestDispatcher.js:210:59)",    
" at step (/var/task/node_modules/ask-sdk-runtime/dist/dispatcher/GenericRequestDispatcher.js:44:23)",    
" at Object.next (/var/task/node_modules/ask-sdk-runtime/dist/dispatcher/GenericRequestDispatcher.js:25:53)",   
" at fulfilled (/var/task/node_modules/ask-sdk-runtime/dist/dispatcher/GenericRequestDispatcher.js:16:58)"

]   
}
```

The lines in the code-

```js
const ErrorHandler = {
    canHandle() {
        return true;
    },
    handle(handlerInput, error) {
        const speakOutput =handlerInput.t('ERROR_MSG');//line 133:error
        console.log(`~~~~ Error handled: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .reprompt(speakOutput)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
```

I don't know why `handlerInput.t` suddenly doesn't work, however the problem is in `errorIntentHandler`, so besids this error, we have the original error.

I tried to debug using my own Node.js endpoint (which, unsurprisingly, didn't work), and it seems that there is a problem with the the endpoint connection.

When it worked before, I usually received a request JSON into my commend line, but now the connection fails before that.

**Note:**
I tried to open a lot of new projects, so I could check this out.

It didn't worked even after creating new project with `ask init` and immediately `ask deploy`.